# SSL Client Identity Keystore - Resolve Identities on Demand via FileInputStream

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore

I'm looking for the best practice in a not so common use of SSL in the client side identity store when handling multiple sets of identities on demand.

Let me just make that clear, this question is about the client side handling of keystore (Java).

Since this is my first time dealing with SSL, my research lead me more in the direction of common best practice such as:

- Have a separate keystore for your trust. (eg. `truststore.jks`)
- A separate keystore for your identity. (eg. `keystore.jks` - private keys)

This part is quite clear and it totally make sense when I think about how browser certificate works where I accept the server's certificate and at the same time the server recognizes my certificate (identity) and even in Firefox which is cooler' because it allows me to pick which certificate to present.

Through code, I relied in the use of `Keystore.load(FileInputStream)` so that I actually pick the trust and key store to use before I build my `SSLSocketFactory` (apache).

So all is well and good but here's the complexity, in business terms, my webapp supports N-Identities at any given time. These identities can even switch in a single session. I'm specifying identities here because these identities will potentially have a different *privateKey* + *cert* contract with a hosting site. Different in the sense that their validity (eg. valid till 350 days) will be different and definitely the *RDN* (eg. `CN=Foo, OU=Foo`, etc) will be different.

So my first attempt was to create one giant keystore and import everything there - provided they have unique aliases. This was OK at first, but then for every new host with a new contract, different keys had to be reloaded again and now I'm getting into an alias mapping issue.

So here's the alternative, I'm thinking of creating separate filestore path for each identity. So in essence `IdentityA` goes to `D:\security\<b>A</b>\keystore.jks` and `B` goes so forth and so on. `A` and `B`'s additional private keys can be loaded in their own respective keystore. Of course truststore will be the same for all of the identities, but their keystores will be looked-up and loaded as and when it is needed.

I'm not 100% sure if the direction I'm taking would be the best way in dealing these scenarios but I'd like to get some inputs from other people who most likely already encountered something similar.

Comment: I think the `KeyStore` interface can actually be implemented as well, but that's a lot of work and no fun. Same goes for `KeyStoreSpi`, but you'll have to create a provider for that (and get your code signing certificate from Sun). Upshot is that you can create a safer implementation for your use case.

Comment: I tried something similar but not as fine-grained as touching the KeyStoreSpi. I created a decorated KeyManager to resolve and filter the filtered aliases that matches what the host recognizes. But going with the designated keystore route allows me to identify the operation callee as a single entity beforehand.